# How to add content block to magento admin dashboard?

Tags: php, magento

I want to add a new content block to the magento admin dashboard. I have googled the hole day but cant find a solution. I want to place the block on te red line of the picture.

[image: Magento admin dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

Let's check step-by-step:

**Template** (app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/index.phtml), line 98

```
<div class="dashboard-container">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher') ?>
<table cellspacing="25" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Start including the sales blocks -->
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sales') ?>
            <!-- End including -->
            <div class="entry-edit">
                <div class="entry-edit-head"><h4><?php echo $this->__('Last 5 Orders') ?></h4></div>
                <fieldset class="np"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('lastOrders'); ?></fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-edit">
                <div class="entry-edit-head"><h4><?php echo $this->__('Last 5 Search Terms') ?></h4></div>
                <fieldset class="np"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('lastSearches'); ?></fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-edit">
                <div class="entry-edit-head"><h4><?php echo $this->__('Top 5 Search Terms') ?></h4></div>
                <fieldset class="np"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearches'); ?></fieldset>
            </div>
        </td>
```

You can see the `$this->getChildHtml('sales')` include. Thats responsible for those two blocks *Lifetime Sales* and *Average Sales* from your screenshot.

This template is coming from the Block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard` in which you can find a `_prepareLayout()` method.

**Block class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard** (app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php)

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    ...
        $this->setChild('sales',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/dashboard_sales')
        );
    ...
}
```

As you can see, it sets the block 'sales' with the block class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Sales`.

**Block class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Sales** (app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Sales.php)

*Now it gets interesting! :)*

Check the `_prepareLayout` method...

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    if (!Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Reports')) {
        return $this;
    }
    $isFilter = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('website') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('group');

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection')
        ->calculateSales($isFilter);

    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'));
    } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('website')){
        $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getRequest()->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));
    } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('group')){
        $storeIds = Mage::app()->getGroup($this->getRequest()->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));
    }

    $collection->load();
    $sales = $collection->getFirstItem();

    // HERE YOU GO!
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Lifetime Sales'), $sales->getLifetime());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Average Orders'), $sales->getAverage());
}
```

What you (hopefully) see:

1. Those two blocks are only shown if `Mage_Reports` is enabled
2. The blocks are basically hardcoded here
3. If you want something in between rewrite the `_prepareLayout` method with your own
  3.